# MySQL : Getting Unknown column error

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm getting an error that I'm not being able to solve. I'm rather new at SQL, so I imagine this is quite an idiotic error, but I'd really appreciate somebody's help with this.

I'm trying to see if there are rows in a certain table that were created in the current week (From monday on). So I wrote this.

```
SELECT 
  *, 
  DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE,INTERVAL ( DAYOFWEEK(CURRENT_DATE) - 2 ) DAY) AS `week_start`,
  CASE WHEN `ganador`.`fecha` >= `week_start` THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS `this_week`
FROM `lesaffre_ganadores` as `ganador`
```

I'm getting the following error:

> ## 1054 - Unknown column 'week_start' in 'field list'

I assume there is a way to define the variable week_start in order to be able to use it in the query, but I really ignore it.

Could anyone help me?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
*,
CASE WHEN `ganador`.`fecha` >= `week_start` THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS `this_week`

FROM
(
SELECT 
  *, 
  DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE,INTERVAL ( DAYOFWEEK(CURRENT_DATE) - 2 ) DAY) AS `week_start`
FROM `lesaffre_ganadores` 
)ganador
```

Comment: This worked really well. I get what my error was. Thanks a lot.